# How i can adjust the all elements that web page has?

Tags: css

I have a web page, and when I am zooming, all the elements that are there in the page move.

How do I modify my CSS file in order to fix this issue?

Comment: You'll have to elaborate your question more if you expect any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you zoom the page using: <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> OR <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> your browser is changing the layout of your page.

The is no way in JS to capture this zoom event , the only thing you can do it to catch the `resize` event and "fix" your page layout there.

Comment: I have reviewed some informations and i think that i  have all "px" in my CSS and  put "%" .